# Word Professional Plus 2021: how to change background color of pasted text to transparent

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, colors

From a YouTube comment, I tried copying and pasting text into a new Word document, and it looked like this:

[image: pasted YouTube comment]

Then I selected all the text in Word and changed its font color to black, but then (as expected) it looks like this:

[image: black on black]

Font > "Text Highlight Color" is already set to "No Color".

Paragraph > "Paragraph Shading" is already set to "No Color".

Paragraph > Borders > "Borders and Shading" > Shading is already set to "No Color".

What other settings exist that cause a background color?

(Where else do I need to set to "No Color" or "Transparent"?)

I'm 99% sure I've learned of the way to solve this before with another less prominent setting, but I just can't remember it.

P.S. I don't want to use the "Clear All Formatting" approach because I want to preserve italics, etc.

Comment: Shading is also something that can apply to selected text. This is not the same as highlighting. It is under the borders and shading control.

Comment: Right, and I'd already tried that, as I mentioned in my question. The fix, though, was to NOT select ALL text. THEN changing Shading to "No Color" worked.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer!

1. <del>Select all text</del> Actually, selecting *all* text via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> caused this not to work. I needed to select only *most* of the text, excluding its final character (and I don't know why).
2. Right-click the selection
3. See a context menu that pops up near your cursor
4. Set "Shading" to "No Color".

[image: right-click menu]

Alternatively, now that I realized that selecting *all* text first was the problem, one of the solutions I mentioned in my question actually does work:

Paragraph > Borders > "Borders and Shading" > Shading > "No Color".

Weirdly, if I select all text first (such as via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>), neither solution works.

Comment: A much simpler solution is to paste as plain text. Pasting formatted text from other formats is almost always going to produce formatting anomalies. http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/CleanWebText.htm

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Sure, I use "paste without formatting" many times per day, but in this case (as I mentioned in my PS in the question), I wanted to preserve italics, etc.